# Is a comparison of all elements in an array in O(n) possible?

Tags: arrays, time, find, greedy

I've got an unsorted array of the length n. Is there a way to find out if there are equal elements in the array in O(n)?

You know that you can read from the array in O(1)..

Comment: What is in the array? If integers, then what is the possible range?

Comment: Is extra space allowed? Then yes. Else no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a function `foo` that maps each element to a unique integer, and that set of integers is bounded from `0` to `n`.

Then you can declare an array `arr` of boolean types of size `n`.

You then traverse your array of elements, calling `foo` on each one to yield an index `i`. You check `arr[i]` to see if it's been set to `true`. If it has then you don't have a unique set of elements. If `arr` doesn't have that element then set `arr[i] = true`.

That is O(N) but expensive in terms of storage.

Comment: I don't think creating the array is possible in O(n), is it?

Comment: It's a call to an OS, and certainly wouldn't be worse than O(n). *initialising* it is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

- create an empty dictionary
- for each element in the list

  - if the element is already in the dictionary, return true
  - else add the element to the dictionary
- if you reach the end of the list, return false

Comment: I think this is contrived since insertion into a dictionary is not O(1). You're merely kicking the complexity can down the road.

Comment: Tbh I've never heard of the data structure of a dictionary. But running through the dictionary and checking all elements being equal to the one I'm comparing can't be done under log(n), can it? So I would still need n*log(n).

Comment: @M.Dou why? dictionary access is O(1). So you need `O(n)*(O(1) + O(1)) = O(n)`

Comment: @enrico.bacis If dictonary access means to get 1 element at a certain place I'd need O(n)*(O(0)+(1)+...+O(n-1)) to check all elements.